# Script doesnt put information

Tags: php, phpbb

I have written a script in php to replace in newtopic button in phpbb3

in other question, a user says me this:

> In your `submit.php`, you can retrieve the forum ID using `$_GET['f']`. Now, to pass it on to `application.php`, you can use a hidden input field:

```
<form  method="post" action="application.php" accept-charset="utf-8" >
  $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['f']); 
<input type="hidden" name="forum_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
```

When you click on the submit button, the forum ID value will also get POSTed, and you'll be able to retrieve it in application.php code using the `$_POST['forum_id']`.

and my code goes as here:

```
<form  method="post" action="application.php" accept-charset="utf-8" >
   $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['f']); 
  <input type="hidden" name="forum_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
  .............
<fieldset class="submit-buttons">
               <input value="Submit" class="button2" type="submit">
           </fieldset>
```

This code is embedded in submit.php to use phpbb3 template.

and application.php goes as [here](http://pastebin.com/EXXCpeUR)

So I click on new topic button, and I redirect to `submit.php?mode=post&f=3` and in that php there is embedded the html, the problem is that with the solution, I receive the next error:

`"The forum you selected does not exist"` and the addresswar goes as: `viewforum.php?f=&sid=a69fb9f491d2adc11c4be3a6dac02774`

so I think that forum_id (in thos case is "3" (&f=3) is not correctly sent throught php scripts

I would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['f']);` inside the `<?php ?>` tag,

```
<?php  $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['f']); ?>
```

Comment: i have added that, and the problem persists.... could you tell me how i need to get the forum id in application.php?

Comment: Are you passing through url or Post value ?

Comment: If you have used post then <?php echo $forum_id =$_POST['forum_id'];?> or if it is passed through url then <?php echo $forum_id = $_GET['forum_id'];?>

Comment: Am not sure, am understand your comments